# Why is my code not sorting correctly? Or what changes need to be made to it?

Tags: python

I am supposed to get input for a few bowlers, and their scores. Then output the top score, lowest score and the average team score. My code will not sort the scores correctly.

```
def myMax(list): 
    maxVal= -100000 
    maxIndex = -1 
    for i in range(len(list)): 
        if list[i] > maxVal: 
            maxVal = list[i] 
            maxIndex = i 
nsList = []
while True:
    temp = input("Enter Bowler and thier score by Name, Score ")
    if(len(temp)==0):
         break
    split_list = temp.split(' ')
    score=int(split_list[1])
    nsList.append((split_list[0],score))



#end of loop
#print ("The high score is ", maxVal)
print(nsList)
print ("The high score is", (nsList[0]))
print ("Sorry" , nsList[-1], "has the lowest score")
```

Comment: "My code will not sort the scores correctly"—in what way, specifically? Please see [ask].

Comment: Hello! `list` is a built-in function in python. Do not use it as a variable name. Besides this, you never use the `myMax` function or perform any kind of sorting, so I would say your code does not sort anything at all.

Comment: What is the result of your code? What does you expect?

Comment: You never call `myMax`.

Comment: `myMax` doesn't return anything, though I'm not sure why you're reimplementing `max()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list in descending order with the following:

```
nsList.sort(key=lambda v : v[1], reverse=True)
```

Put this after your `for` loop that builds `nsList`, and you'll be good.  You don't need your `myMax` function.

Btw, you should make it clear what your input format is in your prompt message.  You currently say: "Enter Bowler and thier score by Name, Score ". This suggests that you should put a comma between Name and Score, but your code requires a single space character between them to work correctly.  Alternately, you could beef up your input parsing code to be more flexible in the input it takes.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I Added it, now I just need to pull out the scores and find the average. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: C'mon.  That one's really simple.  Just iterate over the list, adding each score to a total variable that starts at 0, then divide that by the number of items in the list.  You should be able to figure that out yourself.

Comment: @Steve or just `sum(list) / len(list)`

Comment: yes...indeed @wjandrea.  I was trying to point him at the simplest of approaches where he might do some of the thought work.  It wouldn't quite be `sum(list)` right, because he needs t sum the second element of each tuple in the list?  If we went that far with it, we'd be giving him the answer again.